# Basic pixel shader in XNA : incomprehensible bug with two textures

Tags: xna, shader

So I'm new to shaders (using XNA), and I'm getting a super-weird bug that I can't explain. Consider the following pixel shader function :

```
float4 BasicTest(float2 coords: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0  
{
float4 src=tex2D(s0, coords);
float4 dst=tex2D(s1, coords);
float4 color=src;
if (coords.x>0.5) color=dst;
return color;
}
```

This displays the texture `src` on the left side of the screen, and `dst`on the right side, as expected. However, if I instead simply use :

```
float4 BasicTest(float2 coords: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0  
{
float4 src=tex2D(s0, coords);
float4 dst=tex2D(s1, coords);
float4 color=dst;
return color;
}
```

I get `src` on the whole screen!

Apparently, the shader refuses to display `dst` at all unless it's in an expression of some sort (`color=src*0.5+dst*0.5` also works normally). I guess I could cheat around that issue (`if (coords.x>=0)` maybe) but I'd really rather know what's causing it!

If you need additional details about my code, please tell me.

Comment: A wild guess: Maybe the shader compiler (which has a few bugs, here and there) is optimising away `s0` because it is never used, incorrectly shifting `s1` down.

Comment: Ooh... maybe. That's some overzealous optimizing then!

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird bug indeed.

If your using ps 2.0 or higher:
Register your samples like this:

```
sampler tex0: register(s1);
sampler tex1: register(s2);
```

else for lower pixel shader versions, use t1, t2, t3...